# Linux Mint Petra won't Auto-Mount USB Devices

Tags: linux, usb, mount, linux-mint

I recently updated my OS to Mint Petra and am no longer able to plug-and-play my USB devices. Olivia would automatically mount my jump drives or external hard drives, and I don't see why Petra shouldn't. I've tried `sudo fdisk -l` and see that the system recognizes the device. I can mount them up with the `mount` command, but I would really rather not have to do that every time I plug in a device. I've also run `update` and `upgrade`, but that didn't seem to fix anything.

Thoughts?

**Update**

I updated my OS to Mint Quiana and still can't automount drives (Or CD's). I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.linuxformat.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=109844). I used the Synaptic Package Manager to uninstall the udisks utility and install the udisks2 utility. I rebooted the computer, and my problem was solved! It seems like maybe my in-place upgrade between Linux Mint versions didn't upgrade the udisk utility; maybe the newer versions are not compatible with udisks.

Comment: Following the first option of the link helped me. Removing `/etc/mtab.fuselock` and then rebooting did the thing.